# How can I run a vb function every minute in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net

my question is simple, How can i set a timer to run and execute a function in jquery?

for example i want a vb function to be executed every minute for example. how can i do it in jquery?

the following code executes the function once. I want it to be executed every minute. how?

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/CheckPending",
      data: '{}',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: alert("Success"),
      error: alert("Error")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this only runs once because you run it on the window.load event.

to have it run more than once, use this function.

```
window.setInterval("javascript function", milliseconds);
```

in this case:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    window.setInterval(
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "Default.aspx/CheckPending",
           data: '{}',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: alert("Success"),
           error: alert("Error")
        })
    ,60000);

});
```